# When did Ross get his Ph.D.?

Tags: friends

The *Friends* episode "The One Where the Stripper Cries" establishes that Ross and Chandler did their undergraduate degrees from 1987 to 1991.

If I remember correctly, it's established that Ross already works at the museum when the show starts, around 1994. Either he already had his Ph.D. at this time, or he was still completing it sometime during the first few seasons.

Is it ever established specifically when he got his Ph.D.?

Comment: What was his job at the museum? It is possible that he was working there while doing his PhD. I read recently that it is hard to get funding in paleontology.

Comment: I don't think it's established when he got his Ph.D. By the time the first episode airs, he's already working as a paleontologist at the museum.

Comment: I don't think Friends talked about the professional back-story of it's characters. No on know how Chandler got his jobs, what motivated Monica to be a cook etc.

Comment: @AnkitKante Monica became a chef because Chandler said she should, it was shown in a flashback episode.

Comment: I don't feel that this is trivia, i feel that there could be a good answer to this question, especially with good citations

Comment: Is there a reason that he can't have completed his Ph.D between 1991 and 1994? My mum started her undergraduate degree in 1987 and completed her Ph.D towards the end of 1994 and then went straight into work (after a very short break because she had me in Oct 1994), but that's in the UK and I know the US had a different system

Comment: Here I think it's about 10 years total, 4 Years Bachelor, 2 Years Masters, another 4 for Ph.D. That's assumes full time student, if you were part time it would be longer.

Comment: @Tronman - I posted an answer, if it helped you, you should check mark it.

Answer (score 4):

Being the massive Friends fan that I am, I'll try to piece together the information and come up with an answer.

We first have to look at the Thanksgiving episode [The One with all the Thanksgivings](https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0508.html). Ross introduces Chandler as his roommate and band member.

**Thanksgiving 1987:**

> Ross: (entering) Hey!
>
> Mr. Geller: Oh my!
>
> Ross: Uh, everyone, this is Chandler! My roommate and lead singer of
> our band!

Given that this is the first time the family meets Chandler, I'm **guessing** this is Ross and Chandler's first year or even semester in college. If not, this means he had a roommate for a lot longer and he didn't mention at least a name to his parents.

> Ross: So I’m thinking about asking Rachel out tonight. Y'know maybe
> play her that song we wrote last week.
>
> Chandler: Emotional Knapsack?
>
> Ross: Yeah.

The next flash back happens in [The One where the Stripper Cries](https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/1011.html):

**Note**: Ross and Chandler are at a Class of **'91** reunion

**Flashback, Year 1987**

> Ross: Hey. Hey, check out the flyers for the band. I made 'em on a
> Macintosh in the computer room!
>
> Chandler: Awesome, the name really stands out.
>
> Ross: Thanks to a little something called "Helvetica Bold 24 point"!

[The One with all the Thanksgivings](https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0508.html):

**Thanksgiving 1988**

They remain friends and room mates, and again Chandler is invited to Thanksgiving, only this time Monica is thin.

[The One With the Sonogram at the End](https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0102.html):

**The first appearance of the museum**.

> Museum of Prehistoric History, Ross and a co-worker (Marsha) are
> setting up an exhibit which includes some mannequins of cave people

Assuming the air date is also the same date in the episode, and that the museum requires a Ph.D to work there, it takes place in 1994.

Comment: This summarizes nicely what we already know, but I was hoping for either a direct quote from the show with regard to his Ph.D. (at best) or second to that, a behind the scenes quote explaining the discrepancy or admitting it as a goof.